# Factory functions advice/explanation

Tags: python, function, math

I have started this question regarding bear options however I am unsure how to proceed with the factory function part:

a) A bear option has payoff
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc4Fe.png)

I have to write a python function which returns the value of the payoff.

```
def bear(S,K):
    if S <= K:
        value = K
    elif K < S and S < 2*K:
        value = 2*K - S
    else:
        value = 0
    return value
```

The next part... b) "Also write a factory function which returns a bear option payoff function of one variable, with K fixed."

I cannot find a simple explanation of what a factory function is, I am just starting to code and my notes have no mention of factory functions as of yet. Any links to web pages, hints or explanations will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try searching google for factory design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they want you to do is write a function that returns another function, which can be used to compute `bear(S, K)` for a fixed value of K.

```
def bear_for_k(K):
    return lambda S: bear(S, K)
```

Demo:

```
>>> bear(21, 17)
13
>>> bear_for_k17 = bear_for_k(17)
>>> bear_for_k17(21)
13
>>> bear(112, 81)
50
>>> bear_for_k81 = bear_for_k(81)
>>> bear_for_k81(112)
50
```

edit in response to comment:

Try the following file:

```
def bear(S,K):
    if S <= K:
        value = K
    elif K < S and S < 2*K:
        value = 2*K - S
    else:
        value = 0
    return value

def bear_for_k(K):
    return lambda S: bear(S, K)

#test:
print(bear_for_k(17)(21))
```

This *will* print 13, without errors, in Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's kind of obvious now that I look at it :/ Unfortunately I am getting a "name 'bear' is not defined" error. Do you know why that could be? I will be searching online for an answer and hopefully I can solve the issue.

Comment: @G.Ben That means the function `bear` which you posted in your question cannot be found, are you sure it is in the same file or that you have imported it?

Comment: yes, I have just created a new file with just the code I showed and the one you suggested but the same error appears in the python console. Could it be the version I am running?

Comment: Apologies! I hadn't run the file so the console wasn't sure what it was doing, thanks again for your help!